# Scrolling animation issue using Greensock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, gsap

I am using GreenSock(https://greensock.com/get-started-js) for animation.

The issue is, when I am scrolling the mouse wheel downside then animation is working from right to left. This is not a right. I need when mouse scroll wheel up then animates from right to left and mouse scroll wheel down then animate from left to right. I need a fast scroll.

when mouse wheel scroll fast than how can animate the fast from right to left and vice-versa?

I tried some code but not working.

would you help me out in this?

```js
/*scroll the page horizontal*/
(function() {
  var content = document.getElementById("content"); // container of scrollable content
  var xScroll = 0;  // initialize virtual scroll position
  var ignore = false; // ignore flag, decides whether xScroll needs to be updated (user scrolls via scrollbar) or not (user scrolls via mousewheel)
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {
        // every browser gives another e.deltaY -> only get the current direction and set an own speed
        var direction = (e.deltaY>0) ? 1 : -1;
        xScroll = xScroll+direction*120; // calculate new virtual scroll positon -> scroll position at the end of animation
        // set limits to avoid overshooting and stucking at beginning or end
        var max = content.scrollWidth - content.clientWidth;
          if (xScroll <= 0) {
              xScroll = 0;
          } else if (xScroll >= max) {
              xScroll = max;
          }
        ignore = true; // user scrolls via mousewheel -> block updates of xScroll until animation ahs finished
        // scroll smooth to xScroll
        TweenLite.to(content, 1, { ease: Power1.easeOut, scrollTo:{x:xScroll} });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    function updateXScroll(e) {
        if (xScroll == content.scrollLeft) {
          // scroll animation has finished -> reset ignore flag -> xScroll will be updated again
          ignore = false;
        }
        if (!ignore) {
          // if scroll event was NOT fired by mousewheel, update xScroll
          xScroll = content.scrollLeft;
        }
    }
   if (content.addEventListener) {
        // Standard
        content.addEventListener("scroll", updateXScroll, false); // update xScroll at scrollbar scrolls
        content.addEventListener("wheel", scrollHorizontally, false); // make smooth scroll animation when srolling via mousewheel
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        content.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
    }

})();
```

```css
#content {
   position:fixed;
display: inline-block;
overflow-x: scroll;
width: 100%;
overflow-y: hidden;
top: 0;
right:0;
height: 100%;
}
#content > div{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:350%;/*to increase the width */
}
.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100
{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
}
.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100 article{
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    border-left: solid 1px #E2E2E2;

}
```

```html
<div id="content">
        <div class="horizontal_scroll">
        <div class="full_screen_100">
            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </span>

        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>

        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </span>
        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        </article>

     </div>
    </div>
    </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the minus (`-`) before `delta*40`

```
TweenLite.to(content, 0.5, {scrollTo:{x:content.scrollLeft - (delta*40)}})
```

```js
(function() {
    var content = document.getElementById("content");
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {

        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
       // ; // Multiplied by 40
        TweenLite.to(content, 0.5, {scrollTo:{x:content.scrollLeft - (delta*40)}})
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (content.addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        content.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
        // Firefox
        content.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        content.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
    }
})();
```

```css
#content {
   position:fixed;
display: inline-block;
overflow-x: scroll;
width: 100%;
overflow-y: hidden;
top: 0;
right:0;
height: 100%;
}
#content > div{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:250%;/*to increase the width */
}
.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100
{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
}
.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100 article{
    width: 900px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    border-left: solid 1px #E2E2E2;

}
```

```html
<div id="content">
        <div class="horizontal_scroll">
        <div class="full_screen_100">
            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </span>

        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>

        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </span>
        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        </article>

            <article>
                <span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span>
        </article>

     </div>
    </div>
    </div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, one issue got resolved.Thanks for the help. I need your help on my second issue. I mean When I am scrolling the fast wheel then still scrollbar is scrolling very show.

Comment: @NarendraVerma In the same line, the second argument is the transition time: `TweenLite.to(content, 0.5, {scrollTo:{x:content.scrollLeft - (delta*40)}})`. Here it is set to 0.5 seconds. Just make it lower for a shorter transition time.

Comment: If I change from 0.5 to 0.2 then scrolling section is not going linearly. I mean I have to scroll smoothly

Comment: @NarendraVerma I'm not sure if I understand you. If you set that time to `0` there will be no transition, it will jump to the next scroll position.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, I am trying to animate like this https://www.tentwenty.me/about-us

Comment: @NarendraVerma Ok then you can multiply `delta` by a larger number. `delta*120` for example: `TweenLite.to(content, 0.5, {scrollTo:{x:content.scrollLeft - (delta*120)}})`

Comment: Now the issue is when I scroll little bit mouse wheel it's working smoothly but when I scroll fast mouse wheel it's also working the same. I mean check the scroll bar speed. Slow and fast both effect is showing same. I need if slow mouse wheel then smooth slowly article if fast mouse wheel then the smoothly fast article. like above sample site

Comment: @NarendraVerma That progressive scroll speed would need a little more checks and calculations (For example: get current scroll distance left and add current new current distance). Maybe it would be worth opening a new Question. If you consider the question you asked in this thread is answered, please mark it as answered

Comment: Can you share the code here, Please. It will be a great help for me.